# How to plot inline in VSCode?

Tags: plot, visual-studio-code, layout, julia, inline

I just learned how to make plots in VSCode (in Julia), and I'd like to change how the plots are displayed. I want it to appear either inline (i.e. displayed in the REPL, not in its own panel), or I'd it to appear in the top right of the window, with the REPL occupying the lower right portion. Here is what it currently looks like in VSCode (I am using the gr() backend if that matters):
[image]

And this is how I want it to look:
[image]

Is there a way to do this in VSCode? Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: My setup puts the plot on the side, above the REPL and to the right of the code, by default.  I start with the code in near full width window above a near full width REPL window at plotting time--have you tried that configuration?